# Why do i get this runtime error in this C programme? Please show me what's wrong

Tags: c

The task can be found here: http://www.talentbuddy.co/challenge/51846c184af0110af3822c32

And my programme regarding this task is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void tokenize_query(char *query, char *punctuation) {

    int i,j,ok=1,k,t;
    char x[1000];

    for(i=0;i<strlen(query);i++)
    {
        ok=1;
        for(j=0;j<strlen(punctuation);j++)
        {
            if(query[i]==punctuation[j] || query[i]==' ')
                ok=0;   
        }

        if(ok!=0)
        {
            x[k]=query[i];
            k++;
        }

        else {

            for(t=0;t<k;t++)
            {
                printf("%c",x[t]);
            }

            k=0;
            printf("\n");

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: For what input?   We cannot debug it if we don't have the same input.

Comment: Note that running in a loop over strlen(query) is bad. it is evaluated on every iteration. The evaluation itself requires running to the end of the string.

Comment: In addition to initializing `k` to 0, before `x[k]=query[i];`, OP needs to test to insure `k < 1000`.

Answer (score 5):

`k` is uninitialised in the line

```
x[k]=query[i];
```

so you'll probably try to write beyond the end of the memory allocated for `x`.

The easiest fix is to initialise `k` when you declare it

```
int i,j,ok=1,k=0,t;
//            ^^
```